# Testing a custom Django template filter

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I have a custom template filter I created under `project/app/templatetags`.

I want to add some regression tests for some bugs I just found. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Mr. @Vazquez-Abrams: Then add what? I thought actually rendering a real template would be a bad way to go about it. Wanted to see what techniques others used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I do it (extracted from [my django-multiforloop](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/django-multiforloop/blob/master/multiforloop/tests.py)):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.template import Context, Template

class TagTests(TestCase):
    def tag_test(self, template, context, output):
        t = Template('{% load multifor %}'+template)
        c = Context(context)
        self.assertEqual(t.render(c), output)
    def test_for_tag_multi(self):
        template = "{% for x in x_list; y in y_list %}{{ x }}:{{ y }}/{% endfor %}"
        context = {"x_list": ('one', 1, 'carrot'), "y_list": ('two', 2, 'orange')}
        output = u"one:two/1:2/carrot:orange/"
        self.tag_test(template, context, output)
```

This is fairly similar to how tests are laid out in [Django's own test suite](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/tests/regressiontests/templates/tests.py#L728), but without relying on django's somewhat complicated testing machinery.

Comment: If you set up your tests this way and I end up working for your company and taking over your project I would be furious. Have to update entire expected template output just to test one filter? This is a bad way to set up a "unit" test because it has a dependency on the entire template content.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to test a template filter is to test it as a regular function.

@register.filter decorator doesn't harm the underlying function, you can import the filter and use just it like if it is not decorated. This approach is useful for testing filter logic.

If you want to write more integration-style test then you should create a django Template instance and check if the output is correct (as shown in Gabriel's answer).

Comment: This is the right way unless you have really tiny templates. Should not have to render the entire template to test one filter!